# Reference directory from master branch on gh-pages branch

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I followed the [GitHub](http://help.github.com/pages/) instructions to create a `gh-pages` branch for a javascript library. The library's build script uses JsDocs to create a `docs` directory - I would like my GitHub page to be able to reference those documents.

I have been manually copying the docs directory from `master` to `gh-pages`, but I think a better solution would be to either:

- Set up my `gh-pages` branch to reference the `docs` directory on `master`, or
- Create some type of hook that copies only the `docs` directory to `gh-pages` whenever someone commits to `master`

How can I provide this documentation to users with minimal effort and lessen the chance of falling out of sync?

Answer (score 1):

The following will save you from having to checkout the other branch to get at those files:

you can get another branches version of a directory with

```
git checkout master -- path/to/my/docs/dir
```

you can list files in a directory in another branch with

```
git ls-files $(git rev-parse master) -- path/to/my/docs/dir
```

you can stream a specific file from another branch with

```
git show master:path/to/my/docs/dir/somefile.txt
```

Hope this is enough to get you to the next step.